# How to control omxplayer via LIRC?

Tags: remote, omxplayer

After searching different forums for integrating **omxplayer** with **LIRC**, still I haven't found answers to my problem.

I have successfully set up LIRC on my Raspberry Pi B+, and now I want to create a `lircrc` file for it, in order to actually begin controlling the device remotely.
The following is an example I've written on `lircrc` file:

```
begin
    prog = irexec
    button = KEY_POWER
    config = omxplayer my_video.mp4 &
    repeat = 0
end
```

This file works OK; whenever I run `irexec` and press KEY_POWER on my IR remote controller, the omxplayer starts to play the video.

Now I want to add some features like *increase volume, decrease volume, next, previous*, etc. to the `lircrc` file.
I know that pressing some keys like *+, -, arrows*, etc. on keyboard control the video playback on omxplayer; but I don't want to use the keyboard. I just want to do them all by my IR remote controller. (Although I don't want to use keyboard, I just found out that keyboard shortcuts like +, -, etc. don't work at all when omxplayer is running on `irexec` !!)

So what commands should I use to control omxplayer video playback?

I tried something like the following in the `lircrc` file to increase the volume:

```
begin
    prog = irexec
    button = KEY_POWER
    config = +
    repeat = 0
end
```

or even

```
begin
    prog = irexec
    button = KEY_POWER
    config = INCREASE_VOLUME
    repeat = 0
end
```

but unfortunately, neither worked!

**How can I set my LIRC to control omxplayer?**

**What are the true commands for controlling the playback options in omxplayer?**

Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Anybody has any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm surprised to see that nobody is aware of the omxplayer commands!

Comment: Since you have an answer from your post on the Raspberry Pi forums, I would suggest you add the answer here as well or delete this question. Second I would add the same caution to you as they did regarding the comment "nobody cares" and for exactly the same reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `omxd`

https://github.com/subogero/omxd

which is a playlist daemon for `omxplayer`. It works great!

It is very helpful, and I recommend it to all `omxplayer` users.

Answer (score 2):

You should setup up omxplayer to use a named pipe, then have lirc talk to omxplayer over the pipe.

```
mkfifo /tmp/cmd
omxplayer my_video.mp4 < /tmp/cmd
echo . > /tmp/cmd #(initial wait for input via the fifo)
echo p > /tmp/cmd #(p will pause playback)
```

List all options:

```
omxplayer --help && omxplayer --keys
```

It's optional but a good idea to wrap it in a script and have lirc call the script (`omxp.sh play my_video.mp4`, `omxp.sh pause`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Control via FIFO no longer works - see https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/737 but here's a working example with dbus.

1. Run `omxplayer-dbus FILENAME`
2. Use python to connect to dbus and pause playback:

```
import dbus
from getpass import getuser
bus = dbus.bus.BusConnection(open(f'/tmp/omxplayerdbus.{getuser()}').read().strip())
obj = bus.get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer','/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2', introspect=False)
prop = dbus.Interface(obj,'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
key = dbus.Interface(obj,'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
key.Action(dbus.Int32("16"))  # send pause, see https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/blob/master/KeyConfig.h for more
```

Heavily inspired by https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=170004